# How to print float value from binary file in shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, floating-point, binary-data, xxd

I've binary file consisting double float (8 bytes) or just float (4 bytes) value which was generated in the following way:

```
$ python -c $'from struct import pack\nwith open("file.bin", "wb") as f: f.write(pack("<d", 0.123))'
$ xxd file.bin
00000000: b072 6891 ed7c bf3f                      .rh..|.?
```

which I could print it back from Python via:

```
$ python -c $'from struct import unpack\nwith open("file.bin", "rb") as f: print(unpack("<d", f.read(8)))'
(0.123,)
```

The same for 4-byte float, just change `<d` into `<f` (mentioned as `float.bin` later on).

How do I print that value from the shell script using cleaner way (without using Python)? Either using built-in tools (e.g. `printf`), or wide-used external tools (e.g. `xxd`, `dc`, `bc`, `od`, `hexdump`, etc.).

---

For example to print decimal values, I can use `xxd` (part of Vim), e.g. in Bash:

- get the value of first byte:

  ```
  $ echo $((16#$(xxd -ps -s0 -l1 file.bin)))
  176
  ```

  <sup>For 2nd and forth bytes, increase `-s`.</sup>
- get decimal value from all 8 bytes:

  ```
  $ echo $((16#$(xxd -ps -s0 -l8 file.bin)))
  -5732404399725297857
  ```

However I would like to print original floating value (`0.123`) on Unix-family system.
Ideally using some one-liner (to keep it simple as part of the script), so I can assign it into text variable or print the value on the screen.

---

I've tried to use `printf` (on the 4-byte float number to make it simpler), but it didn't work as expected:

```
$ xxd -p float.bin
6de7fb3d
$ printf "%.4f\n" 0x.$(xxd -p float.bin)
0.4293
$ printf "%.4f\n" 0x3dfbe76d
1039918957.0000
$ printf "%.4e\n" 0x3dfbe76d
1.0399e+09
```

where according to this [on-line converter](http://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/), `0x3dfbe76d` is the same as `0.123`, so the hex values are in reverse (what `xxd` actually gives).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This doesn't use **Python** and is a widely-used external tool, **Perl**.

```
perl -e "print pack('d>',0.123)" > file.bin

perl -e "print unpack('d>',<>)" < file.bin
0.123
```

Or you can use GNU `od` utility, e.g.:

```
od -tfD file.bin
0000000                    0.123
0000010
```

Where `-t` parameter specifies the output format for floating-point number (`f`) followed by optional size specifier (`F` for float, `D` for double or `L` for long double), in short `-tfD` can be replaced by `-e` or `-F`. To print only value without address, `-A n` can be specified.

Comment: +1: Sounds like `od` (part of `coreutils`) is even shorter, this works great, thank you. Here is trimmed version: `od -tfD file.bin | awk '{print $2}' | xargs`.

Answer (score 12):

```
od -f <filename>
```

That will dump your file as floats.

`od` is a standard Linux tool, and it's what I use. The manpage reads:

> od - dump files in octal and other formats

Comment: `od -t fD <filename>` for doubles

Answer (score 1):

As a oneliner

```
echo -n "000000000000f03f" | while read -N2 code; do printf "\x$code"; done | od -t f8
```

Comment: It should produce: `0000000                        1`?

Comment: Yep 3ff0000000000000 in little endian is the echo body of my answer, and that value is the IEEE754 binary representation of the real value 1.0e0. Its an example for a little endian machine like any x86

Answer (score 1):

`od -tfD filename` would do the job. Check the specific flags following `od` here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=descriptions-od-dump-file-in-specified-format

Answer (score -3):

You may wish to consider some of the mentioned tools such as `bc` which can be used in arithmetic operations and comparisons - eg:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=1.3141592653581 # variable 1
B=1.3141592653589 # variable 2
if (( `echo $A"<"$B | bc` )) ; then printf "$A is: < $B\n" ; else printf "$B is: < $A\n" ; fi ;
C=$(echo "$A+$B" | bc)
printf "C == $C\n" ;
```

Additional formatting for related numbers and types such as zero may be required; as addressed in some other postings eg:
[How to show zero before decimal point in bc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197896/how-to-show-zero-before-decimal-point-in-bc)

Comment: Great if you've already in float format, but you're missing conversion from hex format representation. So conversion from `3dfbe76d` into `0.123` (in case of 4-byte float).