# How to change double value at specific offset in the file from shell script?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, floating-point, binary-data

I've got 5 double values stored in binary file, in the following way:

```
perl -e "print pack('d5', (0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005))" > file.bin
```

and I'd like to change 5th value from `0.005` into `0.008` in the already existing file.

I'm aware that I can [read the double](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794412/55075) by using GNU `od`, like:

```
$ od -F -An -j32 -N8 file.bin | xargs
0.005
```

but how can I modify one of these values in a simple way in shell?

Does GNU `od` has ability to change it, or I've to use other utilities (like `xxd`), or I should use perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -i -0777pe'my @n = unpack("d5", $_); $n[4] = 0.008; $_ = pack("d5", @n);' file.bin
```

-or-

```
perl -i -0777pe'substr($_, 4*8, 8, pack("d", 0.008))' file.bin
```

Where:

- `-i` - make change directly in the file,
- `-0777` - changes the line separator to `undef`, allowing to slurp the file by feeding all the lines to Perl in one go,
- `-p` - places a printing loop around your command,
- `-e '...'` - allows you to provide the program from the argument