# How can I write binary floating-point values to a file in bash?

Tags: bash, floating-point, type-conversion, ieee-754

Suppose I've set a bash variable to some fractional value (e.g. `x=1.5`). Now, I want to write the value of `x` to a file (e.g. `my_file`) - but not as text; rather, I want to write a 32-bit IEEE-754 floating point value.

Can I do this with bash and standard(ish) Unix command-line tools?

Comment: This may help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794412/2836621

Comment: It's possible with bash builtin only too, as Bash has bitwise operators. It's only then math to build an IEEE-754 representation. However, it would be very slow. Are you looking for a bash only answer ?

Comment: @Zilog80: Not necessarily; I did say "standard command-line tools". Also, a contrived answer would not be great.

Answer (score 3):

(Due to a hint from @MarkSetchell:)

Write:

```
perl -e "print pack('f>',${x})" > my_file
```

While `perl` not strictly a simple command-line utility, it is very popular to have installed; and the code is pretty terse.